# Accessing a class member variable by its name at runtime

Tags: c++, reflection

In the vein of more impossible-but-is-it-really questions:

Is it possible to access the member variable of a class, where the variable's name is stored in a string?

```
class Test
{
public:
int test = 0;
}
string name = "test"; // let's assume we know test is an int.
```

Any chance of getting the value of test, using the string?

One bit of cheating not allowed:

```
enum vartype {
INT,
..
}
```

No forcing the class to register all its variables in a `std::map<string, std::pair<vartype, void*> >`.

All other tricks welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain why you think you need it?

Comment: @ruslik: I don't. I was just curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

To do this, you need to provide some mapping between member variables and the string names by which you intend to access them.

Comment: I'd also add: the variable + function names simply **don't exist** in the final executable

Answer (score 2):

In the realm of really ugly kluges, you could build the program with debug information and have it use that to find the location of the variable in the same way a debugger would.  But other than that, you're out of luck.  C++ doesn't do reflection.

Answer (score 0):

**About why it's not available in C++ and an alternative:** http://en.allexperts.com/q/C-1040/eval-function-javascript-C.htm

It's possible in MATLAB though...
As a very simple example, if you have a matrix updation to do, which goes like:

```
M1=1;
M2=2;
M3=3;
```

And you would prefer that the variable names could be altered so that you could use a for loop, then it can also be done this way:

```
for i=1:3
eval(['M' num2str(i) '=' num2str(i)]);
end
```

I used to do this in Actionscript. Was really glad to find that it's available in Matlab too